# Custom Function not being called

Tags: function, scope

I've been having trouble calling my function in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

void bunky(int);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    bucky(20);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
} 

void bucky(int x)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "My favorite number is " << x << endl;
}
```

When I try to compile this it says, "[Error]'bucky' was not declared in this scope" Any and all help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function declaration is wrong change

```
 void bunky(int);
```

to

```
  void bucky(int);
```